# STL vector and transform c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have some declaration

```
vector<double> ved1(10), ved2(10), ved3(10);
array<double, 10> vod1, vod2, vod3;
valarray<double> vad1(10), vad2(10), vad3(10);
```

How to transform code from this version

```
vad3 = 10.0* ((vad1 + vad2) / 2.0 + vad1 * cos(vad2));
```

to this

```
transform(ved1.begin(), ved1.end(), ved2.begin(), ved3.begin(), plus<double>());
```

Using only vector-STL version.

Comment: This is not a code generating machine.

Comment: I don't see any vectors in this code. And valarray has `operator+` for a reason.

Comment: Would you like to explain this to me please?

Comment: @Mikhail Gritsenko Show some initializers for vectors that can be used to demonstrate the code.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow it can be any preferable values. the point is to make that code working using only vector-STL version

Comment: You keep using the phrase "vector-STL version" what do you mean by that? That doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @ CoryKramer, other guy said I could make it using bind function from c++11.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the same thing, but use a lambda function as the last argument

```
transform(begin(ved1),
          end(ved1),
          begin(ved2),
          begin(ved3),
          [](double a, double b){ return 10.0 * ((a + b) / 2.0 + a * cos(b)); });
```

Comment: thank you, but it says I have to perform this peace without any other methods except vector-STL

Comment: At least now *someone* is using using the `ved` arrays. Now all we need is someone to post something that uses the `vod` and `vad` vectors and the circle of life will be complete.

Comment: You just said you wanted to solve it **"Using only vector-STL version"**, and now you want to solve it without the STL? The `transform` function will work if you use the `vector`, `array` or `valarray`.

Comment: Maybe he means he wants a std function to do what your lambda does. There is no standard function that does that, though.